# converting vba to work on another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Good day, below is a sample of code i am trying to get to work. Normally this lastrow call i run works perfectly in the worksheet but when i try to use on a foreign workbook like below, it doesnt. What am i doing wrong?
thanks

```
Dim rngTestArea As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Double
Dim MyResult As String
Dim geodis, Location As Variant

Ret1 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", _
, "Please select file")
If Ret1 = False Then Exit Sub

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)

lastRow = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: So what does it do when you run it?

Comment: Runtime error: 1004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess *"it doesn't (work)"* stands for *"it doesn't pick the right last row index"*

you have to use:

```
With wb2.Sheets(2)
    lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

so that `Rows.Count` also refers to the wanted worksheet (`Sheets(2)`)

Comment: I was just typing this up too. To add something a bit more to explain ... most likely the reason `Rows.Count` does not work is that the active workbook (the one running the code) is a higher version of Excel where the total row count is greater then the workbook being opened (`.xls`). Since `Rows.Count` is unqualified its defaulting to the greater excel version and when its used against an `.xls` file it errors out since the `.xls` as fewer total rows.

Comment: interesting, definitely wouldn't have thought of this myself. Thanks all, it works just fine now!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, thank you for explanation. Anyhow in the OP specific code the issue isn't about the _right workbook_ but it's related to the _right worksheet_ since `lastRow` is being evaluated right after `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)`. So the active workbook is the _right_ one (bringing along a compatible sheet maximum rows, too), but the active worksheet may not (as it proved to be) since the workbook may open with an active sheet different than the one needed. That's why I noticed _"wanted worksheet (Sheets(2))"_

Comment: I am pretty sure it is about the right workbook. Because any worksheet inside of a workbook will have the same `Rows.Count` but not between two `Workbooks` of different size. Maybe I am wrong as I haven't tested this in a while, but I am pretty sure that is the case.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I was sure that bossman1111 _malfunctioning_ was about a `lastRow` being evaluated with no errors (-> _right workbook_ ) but on the _wrong_ worksheet because the workbook opened on a worksheet  other than `Sheets(2)`. So that it got some 54 instead of some 32 row index. But now I see he stated he was getting a "Runtime error: 1004"  so that I must think there must have been more code lines between `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Ret1)` and `lastRow = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` so as to have the _wrong workbook_ issue

Comment: yes, because even if `wb2` opened on `Sheet1` this line `lastRow = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` would still evaluate on `Sheet2` only the `Rows.Count` would differ across workbooks. Either way, the `With block` was the way to go and I was about to post the same answer, myself :)

Comment: there was no code inbetween. Thanks for the help everyone !